# print() inside function breaks {{}}

Tags: r, tidyverse

I cant seem to understand teh following:

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
filter_gap1 <- function(col, val) {
    #print(col)
    filter(gapminder, {{col}} == val)
}

filter_gap1(country, "Canada")
```

[image]
this code works perfectly and outputs filtered dataset
but when I uncomment the print(), why it returns the empty dataset?

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
filter_gap1 <- function(col, val) {
    print(col)
    filter(gapminder, {{col}} == val)
}

filter_gap1(country, "Canada") #returns nothing
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you are trying to print the object `country` (doesn't exist); if you replace `print(col)` with `print(ensym(col))` it should work as expected

Comment: print() command works: it prints "testcol" although the object does not exists,and next command works- but it produce empty table- I don't understand why it is empty. i understand how to make it work- I just want to understand why exactly my code breaks when I do this

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Hadley here: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6487

Here's a proper reprex:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

filter_gap <- function(col, val) {
  print(col)
  filter(gapminder::gapminder, {{col}} == val)
}
filter_gap(country, "Canada")
#> Error in print(col): object 'country' not found
```

If you have country lying from earlier it will "work":

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

country <- "country"
filter_gap <- function(col, val) {
  print(col)
  filter(gapminder::gapminder, {{col}} == val)
}
filter_gap(country, "Canada")
#> [1] "country"
#> # A tibble: 0 × 6
#> # … with 6 variables: country <fct>, continent <fct>, year <int>,
#> #   lifeExp <dbl>, pop <int>, gdpPercap <dbl>
```

The problem here is because you've forced the evaluation of col, you've lost the information that tidyevaluation would use to do variable substitution, so it just inserts the value of col, "country".